# How to perform the same operation on multiple excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a series of excel files all numbered sequentially, having data that is of the same format, but taken at different times. I would like to perform the same operations on all the excel files, these operations include shifting columns and writing formulas in new columns and adding new rows. I do not want to repeat the same operation multiple times. Is there a way to do operations on one excel file and copy them all to another? Some answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766238/run-same-excel-macro-on-multiple-excel-files) suggest using VBA, which I don't know. Is there a way to do the same without coding?

For reference, I am running office 2016 on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO** there is no way of doing that without macros.

However, if your tasks are really exactly the same you can [record a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8) to repeat them in all workbooks.

Comment: could you also tell me how to copy macros from one file to another. I don't have a lot of experience with them.

Comment: You can specify location of the macro when you start recording, I suggest recording it in a new workbook. Then you can run it in any workbook as far as the file containing it is open. My link gives instructions on running the macros too.